# Not able to extract data from API using R

Tags: r, dataframe, dplyr, tidyverse, jsonlite

I have below mentioned dataframe in R:

DF

```
ID        Code
PO-1      123
PO-3      345
PO-4      222
```

I want to pass the `ID` in api get specific response from the JSON.

I have the api like "https://test.com/path/code-info?ID=PO-1" with header code(x892edrsre34434f).

JSON Format:

```
{"test":1,"FormDetails":{"CusName":"Alex",
"City":"NYC","limit":null,"pincode":null,
"refID":"123456",
"channelID":"YUT009"}}
```

I want to extract the `CusName` and `refID` from API output for each `ID` and `rbind` it with my `DF` to get the following output.

```
ID        Code     CusName      refID
PO-1      123      Alex         YUT009
PO-3      345      Carla        YUT098
PO-4      222      Tim          YUT124
```

I have tried:

```
Get_Df<-GET("https://***.com", 
    path  = "path/code-info?Id=",
    query = "PO-1", 
    add_headers(token, API key))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, your get query does not seems to work correct, try

```r
httr::GET(
  "https://test.com", 
  path  = "path/code-info",
  query = list(Id = "PO-1"),
  add_headers(token, API key)
)
```

or

```r
httr::GET(
  "https://test.com", 
  path = paste0("path/code-info?Id=", "PO-1"),
  add_headers(token, API key)
)
```

Then use `jsonlite` or a different `httr::content()` type to read your JSON

```r
test_list <- jsonlite::fromJSON(test)
test_list$FormDetails$CusName
test_list$FormDetails$refID
```

You can then first loop about your dataframe to get all responses and once you have them in e.g. a list, extract all relevant information to a vector. I would use `lapply` for the first loop and [`purrr`](https://github.com/tidyverse/purrr) for the extraction. To help you further, I'd need more information on the data.